# Oracle Service Cloud Chat get attachments by engagementID

Tags: oracle, chat, oracle-service-cloud

I'm trying to use the attachment OSVC API to attach a file to an incident:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/b2c-service/19d/cxsvc/c_osvc_managing_file_attachments.html

I cannot find a link between the created chat session and engagement ID and the incident that is holding the fileAttachment.

API for incident and file attachment is --> https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/b2c-service/19d/cxsvc/c_osvc_managing_file_attachments.html

API for engagement ID and session ID is --> https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/service/19c/cxscc/c_chat_establish_sessions.html

Using /namedIds APIs i tried to lookup a link between SessionID or EngagementID and Incident without much luck: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/b2c-service/19d/cxsvc/op-services-rest-connect-v1.4-namedids-get.html

Does anyone has any experience with Oracle Service cloud chat API?